# In JavaScript, when looping through a FOR loop, how do I pass the value of the item in an array to an anonymous function?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, anonymous-function, pass-by-value

In JavaScript, I need to loop through a `for` loop to get the value of an item in an array, and pass this to an anonymous function. A simplified example of this is below:

```
var aFunctions = []; 
var aStrings = ["a","b","c"];
for (var i = 0; i < aStrings.length - 1; i++) {
    aFunctions[i] = function () { alert(aStrings[i]); };
}
aFunctions[0](); //alerts "c" instead of "a"
```

I can see why this is happening - the variable `i` is being set to `2` when the loop exits, and then when I call `aFunctions[0]()`, the function fires off and evaluates `aStrings[i]` rather than `aStrings[0]`.

What I want to know is how to get the value of `aStrings[i]` returned within my `for` loop, and not when it's executed.

To give more specific detail, I'm working on a Google Maps page, and the markers are stored in a JavaScript array client-side, and in a DB server-side. I write the array at page-load and after that's complete I want to generate the markers, and give them each a custom InfoWindow with the text set to an HTML string. This is the specific code I use:

```
for (var i = 0; i < tGoogleMarker.length - 1; i++) {
    var text = tGoogleMarker[i][4];
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: new google.maps.LatLng(tGoogleMarker[i][0], tGoogleMarker[i][1]),
                        map: map,
                        flat: false,
                        icon: tGoogleMarker[i][2],
                        shadow: tGoogleMarker[i][3]
                        });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () { ShowMarkerContentPopUp(this, text); });
}
```

Instead of getting the HTML string of the specific marker, I get the text of the last item in the array used for all markers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a closure around the addListener part:

```
(function(text){
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () { ShowMarkerContentPopUp(this, text); });
})(text);
```

This creates a new scope and takes the `text` variable as an argument. It means the `text` inside the closure is protected from being changed outside of the closure.

The same can be done to solve your first example:

```
for (var i = 0; i < aStrings.length - 1; i++) {
    (function(i){
        aFunctions[i] = function () { alert(aStrings[i]); };
    })(i);
}
```

More info on closures:

- [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures)
- [StackOverflow how do closures work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work)

Comment: Perfect, this solution worked for my problem - I appreciate the responses to both of my snippets and the links to good `closure` reference pages.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use closure. Read More about this here:
[How do JavaScript closures work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work)

```js
var aFunctions = []; 
var aStrings = ["a","b","c"];
for (var i = 0; i < aStrings.length - 1; i++) {
    aFunctions[i] = (function(val){
      return function() {
          alert(val)
      }
    })(aStrings[i]);
}
aFunctions[0](); //alerts "c" instead of "a"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var aFunctions = []; 
var aStrings = ["a","b","c"];
for (var i = 0; i < aStrings.length; i++) {
    aFunctions[i] =  (function(arg) { return function() { alert(arg); };})(aStrings[i]) ;
}
aFunctions[0](); // alerts "a"
aFunctions[2](); // alerts "c"
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dbtncehf/

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can avoid needing to worry about `closures` much and still achieve the necessary results. It can be done by attaching each `text` variable to its respective marker. This way your anonymous function can call it using `this.text`

```
for (var i = 0; i < tGoogleMarker.length - 1; i++) {
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    text: tGoogleMarker[i][4],
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng(tGoogleMarker[i][0], tGoogleMarker[i][1]),
                    map: map,
                    flat: false,
                    icon: tGoogleMarker[i][2],
                    shadow: tGoogleMarker[i][3]
                    });
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () { ShowMarkerContentPopUp(this, this.text); });
```

}